# How to convert prediction output of naive bayes into a dataframe object

Tags: r

When I run the predict function I get the output of multiple classes in the form

```
class a , class b , class c , class d
[1,] 0.007883349 0.001882366 0.0004159344 0.003825768 0.0001649481 0.0108488 0.005848486
 class e , class f , class g
[1,] 0.4 0.003
```

I am unable to convert them to dataframes as I need to find the top 3 classes.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got on how to present in data frame format : By putting predicted result it in matrix format followed by it will be converted into the data frame using transposing

```
rw <- as.matrix(predict(model,usr_input,type='raw'))
cc <- as.data.frame(t(rw))
```